# Added method to Ruby class throws NoMethodError in MiniTest

Tags: ruby, namespaces, metaprogramming, minitest

So why is this happening? It has to be a namespace error, I just don't understand where it is. I add a method to Fixnum like so in a file `file.rb`

```
module M
  class Fixnum
    def foo
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

then I'll make a test like so:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require './file.rb' #the path is correct

class SomeTest < MiniTest::Test
  def test_foo
    assert 3.foo
  end
end
```

which will in turn throw a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for 3:Fixnum
```

when I run the test, and I am left scratching my head - even if I `include M` to include the module (applying the namespace?) for the test it still throws the error.  I can use custom classes just fine, it's only when I try to add a method to an existing "open class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have defined your own `M::Fixnum` class which actually has nothing to do with `::Fixnum` in the global namespace. The following will solve an issue:

```
module M
  class ::Fixnum
    def foo
      return true
    end
  end
end

5.foo
#⇒ true
```

Please note, in the code above `module M` has no sense, since the code nevertheless monkey-patches the global `Fixnum`. The code is here just to show how you would monkey-patch the global class from inside another module code.

Plus, Ruby2 introduced [refinements](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), which are likely [what you are intended to use](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-refinements-an-overview-of-a-new-proposed-ruby-feature-3978.html).

Comment: So even though I am including my module - inside the MiniTest test it is not using my module's namespace but the global namespace?  I guess my question is why does it ignore the namespace I am trying to import for the test?

Comment: It does not ignore the namespaces. `5` in the example is an instance of `Fixnum`, which **has nothing to do** with `M::Fixnum` class, declaring `foo` method.

Comment: It does *not* ignore the namespace, that is precisely your problem! The class of `3` is `::Fixnum`, you are defining the class `M::Fixnum`. In other words: it is exactly *because* Ruby *does* honor your namespace that your method gets defined in the wrong class.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ah ok, that makes sense.  How would I go about making the MiniTest use M::Fixnum then if just including the module is not enough? - like enclose the test to M::MiniTest, if that makes sense so that all the calls go through the M namespace?

Comment: @Jeremy: Well, you have to create an instance of `M::Fixnum`, obviously.